# error cannot convert from String to Char while passing path to a different function in a different class

Tags: c#, split, path

```cs
public string FilePath(string path, string newfolder)
{
    string[] pathSeparators = path.Split(@"\",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

is giving me a error cannot convert from String to Char.  Whereas if directly give it like this

```cs
string filePath = @"\\00.00.00.001\kpg data\Transfer\Govind\Cell Block Production Improvement\Cell Block Production Project\Project";

string[] pathSeparators = path.Split(@"\",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then there is no error. So if I pass the base path into a function in a different class, I get the error and if I use the basepath in the same main function and split it there itself no error. What is the problem and how can I solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Your second piece of code is just completely invalid. Your variable declaration doesn't have any quotes around the string literal, and then you're not using the string. Please provide an actual [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.

Comment: What version of .Net? There are a bunch of overloads to `.Split`, like `.Split(string, StringSplitOptions)`, that are not available in all .net versions.

Comment: and your first code block is also invalid since the method doesn’t return anything

Comment: I have updated the second piece of code. That was my mistake when I edited it. I have corrected it. My first piece of code, return type is not important. Return comes after this line. But when there is a error here then the program doesnt go to the next line. I need to fix this. In my actual program there is a return type.